# How to dynamically alter the number of posts per page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to change the number of posts displayed on certain pages on my wordpress site.

I found the following code snippet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19879572/how-to-add-dynamically-number-of-posts-in-a-query-in-wordpress):

```
$postsPage = $settings["postspage"];
query_posts('posts_per_page='.$postsPage);
```

to call before
`if (have_posts()) while (have_posts()) the_post()`

I'm quite unfamiliar with php, but what I'm trying is something like

```
...
if ( is_front_page()) {
$postsPage = $settings["postspage"] + 1;

}elseif ( is_tag()) {
$postsPage = $settings["postspage"] - 2;

} else {
$postsPage = $settings["postspage"];
}
query_posts('posts_per_page='.$postsPage); 
...
```

but unfortunately it is not working. Instead it only returns 1 post for the front page instead of the 5 set in the WP menu + 1. I can hardcode the needed value, e.g. `$postPage = 6;`  for is_front_page and it works without problems.
For some reasons I can't add/subtract anything from the value given by `$settings["postspage"]`. If I don't change the value (else-clause) it also works. What am I missing?

I already tried casting the value of `$settings["postspage"]`to an integer, because I thought maybe it is returned as string. I used: `$postsPage = (int)$settings["postspage"] + 1;` or `$postsPage = intval($settings["postspage"]) + 1;` but without success. Since I'm not really familiar with the wordpress functions and their variables, I'm stuck on finding why I can't modify the number of posts.
I appreciate any hint!

Comment: Are you using `pre_get_posts` to do this? There is information missing. Tell us how and where that code is being executed. How did you get `$settings`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear where you're putting that code, and how you're finding `$settings`, but this should work.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'alter_number_of_posts' );

function alter_number_of_posts( $query ) {

    if ( !$query->is_main_query() ){
        return;
    }

    $posts_per_page = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );

    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $posts_per_page + 1 );
        return;
    }
    if ( is_tag() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $posts_per_page - 2 );
        return;
    }
}
```

`$query` is passed by reference, so any changes you make to it will be reflected in the global query object. You don't need to return it, which means you can safely return from the function within each condition rather than using `elseif`.

Comment: Thanks @Popnoodles for your quick help. I was using the above function in the index.php as my theme is running the `while (have_posts ())` loop there. I didn't know that there's a `pre_get_posts` function Your solution works like charme. Thanks